# [Android]How to capture HTTP(s) without add network_security_config.xml to AndroidManifest.xml on no root Phone?

Tags: android, security

We want app start can capture HTTP(s) when tester open backdoor, and stop capture when they close backdoor.

We do not add network_security_config.xml because we want normal user's http package can not capture.

Is Reflection can do this?

Comment: Sorry but your question is not really understandable. What is "QA" and what back door are you talking about (apps should not have back doors, if they have they are malicious and should be banned)? Based on the other parts of your question you doesn't have understood how network_security_config.xml works. You can add a custom root CA certificate as trusted certificate. Only the users you have access to the matching private (which should not be included in the app) key can make use of this, others not.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, 
QA is tester.
backdoor looks like the backdoor open "developer option".
I think can not add root CA certificate to non root Phone.

Comment: Please read the network_security_config.xml  documentation. Using that file you can reference a trusted root CA for that app. Not on system level, but just for that app.